# With ffmpeg and input of a webm video file, how do I 'play the video'/output in real time to a new webm file and pipe to play in ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, video, webm

Note, I am saying 'real time' in the description as I want the option in ffmpeg where it outputs the video in the same amount of time as the video takes to play. Sorry if I am using the wrong words to describe it here (I'm new with ffmpeg). I'm using this to test a particular scenario mocking an incoming stream. In other words if the 2FPS.webm has a length of 5 minutes, then I expect ffmpeg to take about 5 minutes to run.

So far I am managing to do this if I run two separate commands but would like to do it with just one. How do I do this?

**This is what I'm currently doing.**

In one Ubuntu terminal window I am running:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS.webm -f flv /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS-copy.webm
```

And then in the next Ubuntu terminal window I run this a moment later:

```
ffplay "/home/pete/Desktop/2FPS-copy.webm"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use standard FD pipes.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS.webm -c copy -f flv - | ffplay -f flv -
```

Note that to avoid codec compatibility failures, use the webm format.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS.webm -c copy -f webm - | ffplay -f webm -
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I run it, the video player window does not appear, which was the reason why I wanted ffplay in the first place.

Comment: Ahh it works, but as always I am impetuous, sorry about that. But, there is close to a 10 second delay before it starts, I'm not sure why that is. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Could see how it could be an issue with the video though.

Comment: With a 2fps video, ffplay takes some time to finalize stream parameters discovery, since it relies on examining a number of frames. Remove the `-re`